# Code example for ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Does anyone have a code example of how to properly set up the parameters and use the ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering() API to get sorted subsets of the iPhone Contact list?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following should work:

```
ABAddressBookRef aB = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(aB); // or get the source with ABPersonCopySource(somePersonsABRecordRef);
NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(aB, source, kABPersonSortByLastName);
// you can also use kABPersonSortByFirstName instead of kABPersonSortByLastName
```

Comment: Note: The preferred sort order is ABPersonGetSortOrdering() - this will fill in the sort order by user preference.

Comment: And thanks, this is awesome. It's much faster than getting all contacts and sorting them in code like I've seen in many other examples.

Comment: Has anyone been able to do this in Swift? I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
```