# CFArrayGetValueAtIndex returning non-ABRecordRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I've been having a crash on some user's iPhones and I finally got someone who I can replicate the problem with.  Here's the key segment of the code

```
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
if( addressbook )
{
    //Got this via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641229/code-example-for-abaddressbookcopyarrayofallpeopleinsourcewithsortordering
    ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressbook);
    CFArrayRef sortedPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressbook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
    //Sort them first

    if( sortedPeople )
    {
        CFIndex contactCount = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);

        for( int i = 0; i<contactCount; i++ )
        {
            ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sortedPeople, i);
            NSMutableString *fName = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
            NSMutableString *lName = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
            NSMutableDictionary *identifiers = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
            if( ref )
            {
                //Get the user's name first
                NSLog(@"%@ is the reference", ref);
                CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                if( firstName )
                {
                    NSString *fn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    if([fn hasPrefix:@"(null"])
                        [fName appendString:@""];
                    else
                    {
                        [fName appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstName]];
                        [fName setString:[fName stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[fName substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString]]];
                    }
                    CFRelease(firstName);
                }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Apparently the result of this line of code: 
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sortedPeople, i);

Is sometimes coming back as an NSCFType instead of ABPerson.  Any idea on how to check the type of the result?  I'm trying to prevent this from crashing the user's phone.  Once I get to this line:

```
 ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line.  And it happens when the log file looks like this:

```
2011-09-11 17:24:31.355 Holler[1345:707] <CPRecord: 0x6642fb0 ABPerson> is the reference
2011-09-11 17:24:31.358 Holler[1345:707] <CPRecord: 0x66431d0 ABPerson> is the reference
2011-09-11 17:24:31.361 Holler[1345:707] <CPRecord: 0x66433b0 ABPerson> is the reference
2011-09-11 17:24:31.365 Holler[1345:707] <CPRecord: 0x6640fd0 ABPerson> is the reference
2011-09-11 17:24:31.369 Holler[1345:707] <CPRecord: 0x6643510 ABPerson> is the reference
2011-09-11 17:24:31.372 Holler[1345:707] __NSCFType is the reference
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the crash happens because contactCount is set wrong:

- sortedPeople is set to all people of one source
- contactCount is set to the count of all people in the address book

So if you have multiple sources containing people for your address book, the iteration will leave the bounds of sortedPeople. To fix this, replace

```
CFIndex contactCount = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);
```

with

```
CFIndex contactCount = CFArrayGetCount(sortedPeople);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type-check an Address Book result with `ABRecordGetRecordType(ref) == kABPersonType` to make sure it's an `ABPerson` as opposed to an `ABGroup`.

Comment: This gives an error "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion, passing 'ABRecordType' (aka 'unsigned int') to parameter of type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *')

Comment: Even if I convert to a pointer for example like the code after this comment, it doesn't work.  int test = ABRecordGetRecordType(ref);
                int *testp = &test;
                if( CFEqual(testp, kABPersonType) )

Comment: Oh, sorry, sorry. Correcting that now. Silly me.

Comment: This appears to work though: if( ABRecordGetRecordType(ref) == kABPersonType )

Comment: Yep, I made a booboo thinking a CFTypeRef could be compared to a CFTypeID.